# How to send an Akka actor shutdown message from controller in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, event-handling, akka

I'm new to Akka but really liking the framework already.  I've looked through the [Akka Actor documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html) and some of the Playframework / typesafe tutorials. I have successfully created an actor from a successful POST request in a controller by

```
val reapeter = Akka.system.actorOf(Props(classOf[RepeaterActor], data), name = "repeater")
```

that does a periodic task using a schedule task.

Now I would like to send this actor a stop message from a GET/POST request in a controller. I have tried

```
def stop = Action {
    val sendStop = Akka.system.actorSelection("/user/repeater").tell(Shutdown, ActorRef.noSender)
}
```

and in RepeaterActor's receieve method

```
receieve {
    ...
    case Shutdown => {
        println("shutting down")
        context.system.stop(self)
    }
}
```

But I can't get a response.  I'm not sure if it's a problem with my actorSelection method or how I'm doing the message calls. How can I implement a simple shutdown hook for an actor callable from a controller?  For the time being there only needs to be one of these RepeaterActors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all println is not a good solution. Better use loggers:

```
import play.api.Logger 
val logger = Logger("akka")
logger.debug("shutting down")
```

Second thing is "killing" the actor. There is built-in way to do this is just by sending a [PoisonPill](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/actors.html#Stopping_actors). Also if you want to log [Actor.postStop](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.Actor) method and inside log.

```
def postStop(): Unit = {
  logger.debug("shutting down")
  super.postStop()
}
```

And with this construction you will can inspect if you shutting down properly.

Comment: It turns out the problem was actually in my routing table.  My stop method was never actually getting called. Thanks for the help!